# Comparing dates in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

How do I compare date in the following format with today's date and work out the no. of days in between?

31.12.2016

Formula: A1-Today() doesn't seem to work. It returns #VALUE!

Comment: Is your system setup to recognize the date format with `.` as separators? Maybe Excel is seeing it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)
```

If the NETWORKDAYS function is not available, install and load the Analysis ToolPak add-in.

Comment: NETWORKDAYS doesn't work either. What do I need to do after adding the Analysis ToolPak add-in?

Comment: On the Tools menu, click Add-Ins.
In the Add-Ins available list, select the Analysis ToolPak box, and then click OK.
If necessary, follow the instructions in the setup program.
Should work ok after you have restarted excel

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the DATEVALUE function.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-function-HP010062284.aspx

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the key points in your answer and use the link as reference. Thanks

Comment: The key point is the use of the DATEVALUE function.